# Vdebug Expand All Variable Trees

Tags: vim

Is there a way in Vdebug to expand all the "variable trees" without manually going through each and expanding them?

A picture to explain what I mean by variable trees (the arrow is the top of a tree).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I didn't know about Vdebug, but [from the help file](https://github.com/joonty/vdebug/blob/master/doc/Vdebug.txt):

```
4.2.2 The watch window                        *VdebugWatchWindow*
:
:
To open a closed tree, navigate to a line with a closed tree (right arrow) and
press <enter> (<cr>) or double-click if you have mouse-support enabled. This
will open the tree, and show all the children.

:
:
                                               *VdebugOptions-marker_closed_tree*
g:vdebug_options["marker_closed_tree"] (default = '▸')
Sets the marker used for a variable in the watch window that does have
children, but the tree is currently closed. A "+" symbol is used if multi
byte support is not enabled.
```

So you could use the `:global` command to hit enter on every line containing a closed tree marker:

```
:exe 'g/'.g:vdebug_options["marker_closed_tree"]."/ normal \<cr>"
```

Answer (score 0):

I was not able to get mMontu's answer to work for all occurrences but it did work for the first occurrence.  I also changed it a tad to make it so I didn't have to hit return to actually execute it.

`exe 'g/'.g:vdebug_options["marker_closed_tree"]."/normal \<cr><cr>"`

It also works for "open" markers, which is what I wanted.  For some reason mine are all open by default which makes for hard reading. So, conversely to OP (Kyle) wanted (all open by default) I wanted all closed by default.

`exe 'g/'.g:vdebug_options["marker_open_tree"]."/normal \<cr><cr>"`