# vim hit "enter" on a specific letter

Tags: vim, replace

I want to hit enter on the arrow symbol in a file. Basically after hitting enter the arrow key collapses to show more text. I have so many such arrow keys.

```
▾ $wp_filter = (array [365])
  \
   ▸ $wp_filter['pre_term_name'] = (array [2])
```

After completely collapse

```
▾ $wp_filter = (array [365])
  \
   ▾ $wp_filter['pre_term_name'] = (array [2])
    \
     ▾ $wp_filter['pre_term_name'][10] = (array [2])
      \
       ▾ $wp_filter['pre_term_name'][10]['sanitize_text_field'] = (array [2])
        \
         ⬦ $wp_filter['pre_term_name'][10]['sanitize_text_field']['function'] = (string [19]) `sanitize_text_field`
```

I am trying

```
:%s/▸/\r/g
```

It does not collapse the text and the text after arrow breaks to next line.

```
▾ $wp_filter = (array [365])
  \

 $wp_filter['pre_term_name'] = (array [2])
```

I also tries

```
:%s/▸/▸\r/g
```

It breaks the line after the arrow mark.

```
▾ $wp_filter = (array [365])
  \
   ▸
 $wp_filter['pre_term_name'] = (array [2])
```

Comment: Similar answer to vdebug: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25506551/717124

Comment: I think this is the answer. I am still trying.

Comment: I used `:g/▸/exe "normal \<cr>"` It is working. but it only does for one instance of ▸. I have to run the command many times. Is it possible to recurringly run

Comment: This is surprising, as the default range of `:g` is the entire file, so it should execute in all lines matching the pattern (the `/▸/` on your command). Try to isolate the problem by testing each part of the command separately:  `:g/▸/` - this should print all lines matching the pattern; copy the contents of the vdebug buffer to a regular buffer and try `:g/\S/normal! Aa` - this should append 'a' to each non-blank line.

Comment: I don't know vdebug, but maybe the problem is that when `:g` executes there is only a arrow to hit enter. When this arrow is hit it expands and then display two new arrows, which expand to more arrows. If this is the case you could wrap the above command in a `for` statement (see `:help :for`) and run a large number, or use some stop condition -- for instance check if the number of lines on that buffer stopped changing within a `while`.

Comment: `maybe the problem is that when :g executes there is only a arrow to hit enter. When this arrow is hit it expands and then display two new arrows, which expand to more arrows. ` Exactly that is what the problem looks like. I will try the for loop.

Comment: i looked for help. but i am not able to understand. can you tell me in my case

Comment: `for i in range(5) | exe 'g/▸/exe "normal \<cr>"' | endfor`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61397/discussion-between-santhosh-yedidi-and-mmontu).

Answer (score 0):

see http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Folding or http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/fold.html

particularly: `za` toggles one level of folding, `zA` toggles all levels. You need to be on the node for this to work.

To open all folds in the file: `zR`  (and `zM` will close all of them) (of course here, no need to be on a node, as it acts on all of them)

Comment: Actually this is from the debuggerwatch window of vims vdebug. I typed both za and zA. it says E490:No fold found

Comment: just in case vdebug does use folding (I don't know vdebug...), please try `zR` to open all folds, and `zM` to close all folds. If vdebug uses something else, I let someone else who knows vdebug help you (but you should add that important context information in your question!)