# vim: global not applying on all instances

Tags: vim

I have a collapsable text. (its from vdebugs - debugger watch window). The enter i.e `<cr>` will collapse the text.

```
▾ $wp_filter = (array [365])
  \
   ▸ $wp_filter['pre_term_name'] = (array [2])
   |
   ▸ $wp_filter['pre_comment_author_name'] = (array [2])
   |
   ▸ $wp_filter['pre_link_name'] = (array [2])
```

I have to collapse the text at the arrow mark `▸`. So I use the following command:

`:g/▸/exe "normal \<cr>"`

```
▾ $wp_filter = (array [365])
  \
   ▾ $wp_filter['pre_term_name'] = (array [2])
    \
     ▾ $wp_filter['pre_term_name'][10] = (array [2])
    / 
   ▸ $wp_filter['pre_comment_author_name'] = (array [2])
   |
   ▸ $wp_filter['pre_link_name'] = (array [2])
```

The command works. But it only collapses on one instance. and also not further, recursively.

Is there any way that i run the command for all occurences of arrow mark `▸`
Also if it can apply immediately on the new arrow marks visible after collapsing.

Comment: It seems you are in a hurry... I've just commented on your [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25853291/vim-hit-enter-on-a-specific-letter?noredirect=1#comment40474806_25853291)

Comment: What about using a real graphical debugger?

Comment: It sounds like you may want to collapse all your folds. If so then `zM` might be right for you. See `:h zM` for more information

Comment: The question is answered in `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25853291/vim-hit-enter-on-a-specific-letter`