# vim while loop: execute in silent mode

Tags: vim, while-loop

i have a while loop

```
:let i = 1
:while i < 300
echo "count is" i
let i += 1
g/^     ▸/exe "normal \<cr>"
endwhile
```

After pasting it in vims command, it shows the results of one full page and ---more--- at th end. Then i press space bar it shows next page of results. I have to keep pressing till the while loop ends.

So is there a way that it executes the while loop and not show anyting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove the line:

```
echo "count is" i
```

change the line:

```
g/^     ▸/exe "normal \<cr>"
```

into

```
silent! g/^     ▸/exe "normal \<cr>"
```

check `:h :silent` for details.

Comment: As i have mentioned i have to execute the command with the while loop. If you want to know the reason for using while loop visit http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25853291/vim-hit-enter-on-a-specific-letter. I want to run the entire set of commands in silent mode

Comment: @SanthoshYedidi if you do the modification as my answer tells, you can achieve `it executes the while loop and not show anyting` or not? you can make a function, wrapping your script lines, and create a customized command to call the function. but all those stuffs are not relevant to this question. Here your question is to execute cmds, silently.

Comment: Also if i have another while loop with `silent! g/something/exe "normal \<cr>"`instead, can i execute both the while loops at a time

Comment: @SanthoshYedidi it is up to your requirement. what happened after your `<cr>`. but technical speaking, you can put the two `g/..` in same while loop. if this is what you asked. Basically you cannot start two threads in parallel, vimscript doesn't support that. So you cannot start two loops at same time.

Comment: How to add some delay or wait 2 sec after g in the loop

Comment: @SanthoshYedidi `:h :sleep`